# delphi reformatter suddenly missing

Tags: delphi, ide, reformatting

I was debugging a program and suddenly I noticed that the source code reformatter was not working properly. There was also no longer an entry for the reformatter in the Tools|Options menu. I am using RADStudio_11_3_esd_28_13236.exe. How can I get it back? Just restarting the IDE did not fix the problem. It still reformats as a batch command.

Thanks

I tried restarting the IDE a couple of times and also the batch command line reformatter.

Comment: Why would you be using the code formatter while using the debugger?

Comment: Which reformatted tool? Code formatting can be done with Ctrl + D.

Comment: Have you enabled the formatter? See [Formatting Source Code](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Formatting_Source_Code#To_enable_the_formatter)

Comment: Project>Options>Language>Formatter>Delphi>Profiles and Status. Then check the `Enable Formatter` box.

Comment: @LURD: Actually, it's Tools>Options>Language>Formatter>Delphi>Profiles and Status

Comment: @KenWhite why would that matter?

Comment: @dummzeuch: Because editing code (which would be the reason to be formatting it) while debugging causes the IDE to prompt you with *Code has changed. Restart debugger?* messages, which interrupt the entire debugging process. I was curious what use case the OP has for formatting code when they know it will interrupt the current debugging session.